# CentOS installing rvm error

Tags: git, centos, rvm

i was installing rvm on centos than i got this error. Anyone knows how to solve this ?

```
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.6()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package git.x86_64 0:1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: perl-Git = 1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf for package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: perl(Git) for package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcurl.so.3()(64bit) for package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64
---> Package openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-17.el6.centos.2 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: libcurl.so.3()(64bit)
Error: Package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: perl(Git)
Error: Package: git-1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf.x86_64 (rpmforge)
           Requires: perl-Git = 1.7.11.3-1.el5.rf
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Did you look at the bottom few lines of the output, which showed you why it failed (missing packages) and gave a couple of suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you test after `rvm get head`, we have added support for epel repositories recently.

Please use https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues for reporting RVM related problems.